# Can't start installation of WampServer

Tags: installation, mysql

I installed Wamp server (2.1 e-x32) on my computer, but in the middle of configuring MySQL, I entered the wrong data and I couldn't delete with standard commands (like delete or backspace).

However, I closed the configuration window and uninstalled all programs, but now the computer does not allow me to reinstall all programs.

When I start installation with "RUN" it shows the message

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is inncorect

Does anyone know what this is all about?

Comment: Where did you enter *what* wrong data and why couldn't you delete it?  You can try to remove traces of the previous installation with [Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and see where that gets you.